# Comparing 2 lists of users in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have 2 variables that contains a list of users

```
echo $old_users

1
2   
3
4
5
6

echo $new_users

1
2   
3
4
```

I want to know which users from the old_users list were removed in the new_users list (here user 5 and 6). This is what I have written so far but I still miss something:

```
echo $old_users | while read line
do
  if echo "$new_users"| grep "$line"
then
   echo "$line user was removed"
else
   echo "$line user is still there"
fi
done
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Use `grep -vFxf new_users old_users`

Comment: You need to quote `$old_users` to preserve any newlines contained in the value; otherwise, the `while` loop only sees one line of input.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in $old_users
do
if echo "$new_users"| grep "$line"  #[ You can use grep -w for exact match here ]
then
   echo "$line user was removed"
else
   echo "$line user is still there"
fi
done
```

Hope it will work now.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat similar to https://superuser.com/a/135180. So using that here might be beneficial. This will take the set difference of old_users - new_users.

```
diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' <(echo $old_users) <(echo $new_users)
```